# Why isn't VS Code auto-focusing the first entry in the Quick Open list?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently using VS Code version 1.77.3, and I have encountered an issue with the Quick Open feature. In previous versions, the first item in the selection was always focused by default, so I could simply press Enter to open the file. However, in the current version, I need to use the arrow keys to navigate to the desired item before pressing Enter.

Is this a bug in the latest version of VS Code, or is there a setting that I can change to revert to the previous behavior?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using Windows as my operating system, You don't? So you always have the first one selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was raised as an issue ticket here: [Quick Open does not auto select first item #180302](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180302), where the problem was found to be related to having [Accessibility Mode (Also called "Screen Reader Mode")](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_screen-reader-mode) on.

If you're not really using it, you can turn off Accessibility / Screen Reader Mode by putting the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "off"
```

The before mentioned issue ticket is closed as a dup of [Enter key does not perform default action anymore
#178788](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178788), which itself is closed as a dup of [Don't have any accessibility mode specific behavior of quickpick #176081](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176081)

<strike>If you *are* intentionally using Accessibility / Screen Reader Mode and want this behaviour changed, you'll have to raise [a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md).</strike>

Update for VS Code 1.78 (April Release) (where #176081 got merged and released in). See the section named ["Improved and aligned Quick Pick experience"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_78#_improved-and-aligned-quick-pick-experience), which states:

> Previously, users of accessibility mode experienced different behavior when working with the Command Palette and other Quick Picks. In accessibility mode, the first item of the Quick Pick wasn't selected in order to be fully accessible. This iteration, we've introduced new behavior that allows you to have the best of both worlds: an accessible and fast Quick Pick workflow allowing you to hit `Enter` right away.
>
> **Note**: One tradeoff with this approach is that if an item in the Quick Pick is selected, you are not able to hear ARIA changes to the Quick Pick input box, due to an ARIA limitation. To hear these changes, you can press `Shift + Tab` until no item of the list is selected.